# How to make Linux Fedora stop updating VirtualBox with OS updates

Tags: fedora, upgrade

When my computer updates Fedora, among others, it tries to update VirtualBox. But for some reason, it can't access the repository in VirtualBox.org and so it cannot update my OS. How do I make VirtualBox updates be only manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently at some point my OS got messed up. I just installed Fedora 23 and there is not a problem. There were a lot of other problems with my computer at that time but after I reinstalled Fedora, now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

More appropriate solution is to disable the repo. In `/etc/yum.repos.d/virtualbox.repo`, there is line `enabled=1`. You can change it to `enabled=0` and your virtualBox will not get updated automatically.

Comment: I tried that, and Fedora said that there was some problem with the file... as if I put something wrong in. I have checked and rechecked it, I only have changed that one number. Should I do what Icaro said and entirely get rid of it?

Comment: Posting the "some problem" would help ....

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **.repo** file from the `/etc/yum.repos.d` folder.
The content should be like this http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/el/virtualbox.repo .